# Add space using foundation grid mixins - sass

Tags: grid, sass, zurb-foundation, mixins

I am trying to make a nav bar with sass and foundation grid. I have links in the nav bar, but I don't want them to each be `@include grid-column(4);` instead I would like them to be 3 columns each and then have an empty space of 3 columns on the right end. It would be something similar to this:
[image: navbar]
(the email tab is currently hovered)

How do I add a space there with the Foundation Grid Sass Mixins.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed the issue by just changing each `id` to `@include grid-column(3);` that were previously `@include grid-column(4);`. I believe this worked because they are in a row and the next column down is larger than 3 so it doesn't automatically jump to the nav bar above, but it lays underneath it.

My mixins are laid out something like this:

```
    header {
          @include grid-row;
         }
    h1 {
          @include grid-column(9);
    }
    .login{
       @include grid-column(3);
    } 
    nav {
          @include grid-column(12);
        } 
  #games {
          @include grid-column(3);
       }
    #email {
          @include grid-column(3);
       }
    #archive {
          @include grid-column(3);
       }
    .breadcrumbs {
       @include grid-column(12);
    }
    nav a {
}
```